# Count number of values in query

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm using [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) (7), but I have a beginner's question in PHP.

I have a query :

```
$array = array('1','2','3');
$nb_value = db_select('truc', 'tructruc')
      ->fields('truc')
      ->condition('value', $array)
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();
```

And i want to count how many times it exists every value (how many '1' etc.).

I try this, but it does not work :

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if($value == '1') {
        $nb_1 = count($nb_value);
     }
     if($value == '2') {
         $nb_2 = count($nb_value);
     }
     ...
     print $nb_1
     print $nb_2
     ...
```

Where I'm wrong? 
And foreach is it the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
   if($value == '1') {
      $nb_1++;
   }
   if($value == '2') {
      $nb_2++;
   }
}
...
print $nb_1
print nb_2
...
```

or use this code (optimized):

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
   switch($value){
      case '1':
         $nb_1++;
      break;
      case '2':
          $nb_2++;
      break;
      ...
   }
}
...
print $nb_1
print nb_2
...
```

You also can use SQL command to count your data. as e.g.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "dbusername";
    $password = "dbpassword";
    $dbname = "dbname";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "select truc,count(truc) as cnt from tructruc group by truc";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "Count of (".$row["truc"].")  = ".$row["cnt"]."<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I have errors : `Undefined variable:` for $nb_1, $nb_2 etc. and it doesn't work :( It returns the same number for all the values...

Comment: You have to define your variables with default value (e.g `$nb_1 = 0;`) at the top of your code. Put this e.g. code at the top of your code block.

Comment: I have no more the error, but the number is always the same for all the values... ($nb_1 or $nb_2 etc. returns the same values)

Comment: What is your result value? base on your code, you insert array just one time in your database, so your result will be the same value. Originally you are counting your array values. Try this code as e.g: `$array = array('1','2','1','3','2','1');` and then print it with you loop (foreach);

Comment: My result value is 1 for all number. In fact, I try to find how much it has of value "1" or "2" etc. in database, not in array... Hm, the problem has to come from there. Have you an idea to change how it?

Comment: I edit my answer. I think if you use SQL command is better. Good luck.